# masm ml 'unresolved external symbol' error

Tags: assembly, linker, masm, masm32

I wrote a simple hello world program in assembly. I want to generate its .exe file in windows, but when I link my object file with io.obj I get a linker error: "unresolved external symbol".

Here is my code:

```
    include io.h

   .386 
   .model flat,stdcall 
   ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dwExitCode:DWORD
   .stack 4096

   .data 
      msg db 'hello world!',13,10,0


   .code    
     _start:
          output msg
      invoke ExitProcess,0
    end _sart
       public _start
    end
```

I can assemble the program sucessfully with command:

```
ml /c /coff x.asm
```

But can't link with command:

```
link /subsystem:console /entry:start x.obj io.obj
```

The linker errors are:

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _start
1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol itoa_proc
io.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol itoa_proc
1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol atoi_proc
io.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol atoi_proc
1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol out_proc
io.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol out_proc
1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ins_proc
io.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ins_proc
1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol inc_proc
io.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol inc_proc
1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what does io.h contain

Comment: contains macro definitions for itoa, atoi, output, inputs and inputc
author: R. Detmer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
link /subsystem:console /entry:start x.obj
```

You should not have to link `io.obj` separately as it will be included in `x.obj`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are misinformed on what `io.h` actually does. `io.h` is a header file that is used by a program that includes it, so it is not necessary to link `io.obj`, and in fact, impossible. Other than that, you made some simple syntax errors. Try replacing your original code with this:

```
    include io.h

   .386 
   .model flat,stdcall 
   ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dwExitCode:DWORD
   .stack 4096

   .data 
      msg db 'hello world!',13,10,0


   .code    
     start:
          output msg
      invoke ExitProcess,0
     end start
```

And link with this (same as above):

```
link /subsystem:console /entry:start x.obj
```